# Convert multitab Excel page to database

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have to import a excel sheet into  a datatable. I use the following code
ConvertExcelToDataTable(typeof(example),@....\example\example.xls, "A1", H8)

but my excel file has 3 or more tabs.. what can I use to read every tab?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ImportTest 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ImportData.xls', [Sheet1$])

INSERT INTO dbo.ImportTest 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ImportData.xls', [Sheet2$])

INSERT INTO dbo.ImportTest 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ImportData.xls', [Sheet3$])
```

More info here [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I need something in C#... For one sheet I use this:

`this.FromTable = this.ConvertExcelToDataTable(typeof(ImportText), @"..\Text\FileExport.xls", "A1", "BK7855");`

Answer (score 0):

What about [ExecutNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to insert the tabs?